# jquery after 1minute send $POST to server

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I know how to do a `setTimeout(function(){}),xseconds}`
But what I don't know is how do I make the xseconds a minute.

Basiclly what I want to do is make sure the users session gets updated on our server and the only way I know to do that is via PHP as it needs to be saved to the MYSQL, so I was going to $ajax POST send a request to the server to update the session end time in the session table.

**So quick simple question is what is 1minute in jquery seconds.**

Comment: Just FYI, `setTimeout()` is not a jQuery function, it is a native function of Javascript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's a milisecond not second.
so it you want to have 1 minute means 1x60x1000 = 60000ms

setTimeout(function(){}), 60000}

Answer (score 1):

`setTimeout` is used as follows.

`var t=setTimeout(function(){},milliseconds);`

1000 milliseconds = 1 second. So 60 seconds in milliseconds...

60 * 1000 = 60000

Comment: Please change `"javascript statement"` to `function(){javascript statement;}` before I downvote you lol